# How can I get the value of forms loginurl at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms-authentication

I have this in my web.config:

```
...
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" cookieless="UseCookies" />
    <authentication mode="Form">
      <forms loginUrl="http://myurl" path="/" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="true" />
    </authentication>
...
```

How can I get the value of loginurl at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl`

> Gets the URL for the login page that the FormsAuthentication class
>   will redirect to.

Details at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl(v=vs.110).aspx).